# Wait till R loads an object while executing on the cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing, slurm

I am executing an `RScript` on a `Rivanna` (`SLURM`) cluster. It fails when it tries accessing an object that I am loading with `load()` command. It works fine when I am using `RStudio` interactively, but fails when I submit the script to run as an `sbatch` job task with an error:

> Error in 1:nrow(UMI_count) : argument of length 0
>   Execution halted

I suppose, there are some specific commands to instruct the cluster to wait till the object loads, so what are they?

Here I added the code that fails when I first run it, but somehow works on the second run when `UMI_count` matrix has loaded:

```
# For libraries installation
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

name_of_file <- "GSM2599701_Gene.count.matrix.celegans.cell.Rdata"

path_to_file <- paste0("/home/nikita/Desktop/CElegans_raw_data/",
name_of_file, sep="")
load(path_to_file, verbose=TRUE)

# Removing genes with 0 - counts in all of the columns
num_removed = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(UMI_count)) {
  idx = i - num_removed
...
...
```

Comment: Does the script work when you call it with `Rscript` at the shell? Make sure that works before worrying about submitting it to the cluster/scheduler.

Comment: I added the code, maybe that can help. I am very confused as to why it is not working the first time, but runs perfectly the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by `R` trying to load the required package `Matrix` and executing `nrow(UMI_count)` before it happens. The following addition to the code solved the issue:

```
if("Matrix" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) 
{
  install.packages("Matrix")
}
library(Matrix)

...
```